# 404 error when a trailing period is present in url

Tags: asp.net-mvc, url

I have a ASP.NET MVC page that I send data to in the url like the following:

```
http://localhost:50127/Search/ViewReport/A1225./GIT900554-900
```

I am getting a 404 error.  If I add a character after the period it works fine.  I have tried solutions on here for similar problems but no success. I am running ASP.NET MVC version 4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try to use `<httpRuntime relaxedUrlToFileSystemMapping="true" />` inside `system.web`

Answer (score 3):

a dot is a special/reserved character for a URL, you could try encode it to `%2E`, but its doesn't seem standard to use dots as part of the paths rather than domains?

Comment: That is data I am passing to ViewReport method.  Most of the data doesn't have periods in it.  Only a small subset of the data does.

Comment: Looks like a work-around might be required, ie. replace with "_" and replace back on the other side? depending on what other characters are expected?

Comment: Problem is that I am using this method of passing data in many places in the site.  It would require a lot of work to change.  I was hoping to fix it in one place.  I looked into some web.config solutions but none have worked.